# Mootools Class - Calling a function within a function

Tags: class, mootools

I'm learning Mootools classes at the moment and there's something that I can't seem to get my head around or find a decent example.

Basically, I need to be able to call a function within a different function of the same class; example below:

```
var Bob = new Class({

    initialize: function () {
        this.message = 'Hello';
    },

    someOther: function() {
        this.message2 = 'Bob';
    },

    getMessage: function() {
        return this.someOther();
    },

});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {    
    var map = new Bob;

    alert(map.getMessage());
});
```

From this code, I would have thought that the alert would produce 'Bob' which has been set in the function 'someOther' but it's outputting a undefined message.

Can anyone help or point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

er not quite.

`someOther` has no return value in itself, it's a setter. you invoke it and it will set `this.message2` into the class but it returns nothing. methods should `return this` (the instance, so making it chainable) or a value, when a getter.

anyway, you can make it set the property and return it like so:

```
var Bob = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.message = 'Hello';
    },
    someOther: function() {
        return this.message2 = 'Bob'; //bad 
    },
    getMessage: function() {
        return this.someOther(); // why
    },
});
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var map = new Bob;
    alert(map.getMessage());
    alert(map.message2); // bob
});
```

though, semantically, you want to have 1 getter. `.getMessage` should just `return this.message` - you can write a different method that calls someOther and returns it.

have a look at this pattern for a getter/setter in a class context I wrote the other day:
http://fragged.org/using-overloadsetter-overloadgetter-to-make-flexible-functions-in-mootools_1451.html

etc etc. for more help, look at the keetology blogs or davidwalsh.name - or the mootorial - plenty of examples of class use and structure.

most key ones are listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mootools/info

Comment: Getter/setters patterns, etc, are cool but... Are we sure user should get into it? I mean, look at the error he made: what a mess will be if he starts with patterns, flexible getters/setters, etc? Let's give him time. Basically, the problem was he's missing the return statement. Period. :) *PS: I really really enjoyed you article!*

Comment: yeah, I take your point and agree. however, there may be others than the OP that read this that may benefit from some ideas, you never know--you liked it also (thanks) and you are not __at all__ new at mootools :) ideas and patterns is something I relish and collect, you never know how or when you may find a need for something you have seen previously.

Comment: We all start somewhere, and usually with a mess. The more people you can point in the right direction, the less mess you'll get ;-)